# Selected multiple items clicked with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, fabricjs

I have a canvas and added shapes (circle, square, rect etc.). I can remove the item being clicked following codes.

```
canvas.on('object:selected',function(ev){
    canvas.remove(ev.target);
});
```

But I want to click and select first circle then I will click second circle. When I click second circle, circles should be deleted?

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yrL4eLsn/2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you only have to objects (circles) and you want to remove them when both of them are clicked?

To do this, you can create an empty array, and whenever a circle is clicked, you can check if the array is still empty (and add the clicked object to it). If the array is not empty, then you can remove the object being clicked and the object currently in the array. Something like this should do the trick:

```
var objectsToDelete = [];

canvas.on('object:selected',function(ev){
    if(objectsToDelete.length == 0){
        objectsToDelete.push(ev.target);
    }
    else{
        canvas.remove(objectsToDelete[0]);
        canvas.remove(ev.target);
    }
});
```

Comment: It depends on what you want to do after you have removed the objects. You can empty the array after you have deleted all the objects in case you want to re-instantiate them on the canvas.

Comment: I want to delete same objects. How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

First, added an `id` to each object for later reference.

```
var rect1 = new fabric.Rect({
    id: 'rect1',
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    left: 50,
    top: 50,
    fill: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.5)'
});
```

Then instantiated a variable to keep track of the last selected object. Upon selection, checking what is currently selected, and then checking `last_selected` to see if the mate object was last selected, and if so, `remove` both. And, finally, assigning the object to `last_selected`.

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas(document.getElementById('c'))
var last_selected
canvas.on('object:selected',function(ev){
    if ( ( 'rect1' === ev.target.id && rect2 === last_selected )
      || ( 'rect2' === ev.target.id && rect1 === last_selected ) ) {
        canvas.remove(rect1)
        canvas.remove(rect2)
    }
    if ( ( 'circ1' === ev.target.id && circ2 === last_selected ) 
      || ( 'circ2' === ev.target.id && circ1 === last_selected ) ) {
        canvas.remove(circ1)
        canvas.remove(circ2)
    }
    last_selected = ev.target
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BloodyKnuckles/yrL4eLsn/3/)

Comment: Thanks.I have a circle and a rectangle. I raise randomly.